# copying only upper triangular values of sympy Matrix into array from numpy.triu()?

Tags: python, numpy, sympy

I have a square matrix A (could be any size) and I want to take the upper triangular part and place those values in an array without the values below the center diagonal (k=0).

```
A = sympy.Matrix([[ 4,  0,  3],
                  [ 2,  4, -2],
                  [-2, -3,  7]])
```

using A_upper = numpy.triu(A) gets me to

```
A_Upper = sympy.Matrix([[ 4,  0,  3],
                        [ 0,  4, -2],
                        [ 0,  0,  7]])
```

but from here how would I copy only the upper triangular elements into a simply array? Such as:

```
[4, 0, 3, 4, -2, 7]
```

I was going to just iterate though and copy all non-zero elements, however zero's in the upper triangular are allowed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give a numpy array, this is an easy operation using `numpy.triu_indices(N, k=0)` where N is the size of the square array:

```
In [28]: B = np.array([[4, 0, 3], [2, 4, -2], [-2, -3, 7]])

In [29]: B[np.triu_indices(B.shape[0])]
Out[29]: array([ 4,  0,  3,  4, -2,  7])
```

The `B.shape[0]` is just there in case you don't want to hard code the size of the array (3).

---

Given a sympy Matrix, this isn't as easy, but close enough.  Just convert to a numpy array and make sure you change the `dtype` from `object`.  This should work well if your matrices are reasonably sized.  If they get really big, you might want to rethink this.

```
In [36]: A = sp.Matrix([[4, 0, 3], [2, 4, -2], [-2, -3, 7]])

# you can change the dtype of the new array to match the first array
# e.g., .astype(int), .astype(sp.Symbol)
# or you can just leave the default (dtype=object)
In [37]: C = np.array(A) #.astype(new_dtype) 

In [38]: C[np.triu_indices(C.shape[0])]
Out[38]: array([ 4,  0,  3,  4, -2,  7])
```

To get them into just a plain list, do

```
In [39]: C[np.triu_indices(C.shape[0])].tolist()
Out[39]: [4, 0, 3, 4, -2, 7]
```

Comment: Why do you want to change the dtype from object? That won't work if the matrix entries are symbolic, or even rational.

Comment: That is correct.  I honestly added that to get rid of the `dtype=object` hanging on at the end of `C[np.triu_indices(C.shape[0])]` because the matrix OP provided takes only integer values.  However, if OP will just `.tolist()` the resulting array, then the dtype doesn't matter and he can remove the `.astype(int)`.  I edited the post anyway.

Answer (score 3):

You could do the following:

```
>>> A = Matrix([
[ 4,  0,  3],
[ 2,  4, -2],
[-2, -3,  7]])
>>> flatten([A[i,i:] for i in range(A.rows)])
[4, 0, 3, 4, -2, 7]
```